# How do I make a displayMethod() in AX?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, ax

What are the steps that I have to complete to create a displayMethod() for later use on a TextEdit?

Comment: If you find the answer useful, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a blog post about this, showing how to create a Display Method template inside AX so that you could easily create a new Display method in only a few clicks:
[Enhance your AX 2009 Editor Scripts](http://blog.m1cr0sux0r.com/2011/05/ax-2009-enhancing-your-editor-scripts.html)

Comment: I haven't had the opportunity to play around with 2012 yet, but I believe that it should be fairly similar.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look on [Axaptapedia](http://www.axaptapedia.com/Display_method) (or just use Google search as I did).